# Cpp Protobuf cross-platform

Tags: android, c++, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

I’m trying to develop a c++ ARM dynamic shared library (.so) targeting Android and using visual studio 2019 , my question is what protoc generator should i use to generate my bp files ( that outputs java or c++ ) ?

```
  --cpp_out=OUT_DIR
```

Or

```
  --java_out=OUT_DIR
```

I’m really stuck